# JQuery $.post works in VS 2010 instance but not when I deploy in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have checked the url in $.Post, it's fine.  I have also checked the connectionstring. Everything works great in the entire website including $.ajax commands except one $.post command.  I keep getting "error while saving record" message.

Code I have is that on a jquery dialog box's Save button:

```
var post = $.post(url,
                        $("#myview").serialize(),
                        function () {
                            thisDialog.dialog("close");
                        });
                        post.error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Error while saving the record");
```

This works in local VS instance when I run in debug mode but it doesn't run when I deploy the website to IIS 7.5.  Can someone please guide what the issue can be?  All dlls are present, url is fine too

url is: Home/Start

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Start(StartModel model, FormCollection collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    Service.Create(model);
                    return RedirectToAction("List");
                }
```

this works in VS but not in IIS 7.5

I get error code 500

Stack trace shows error message: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

i am setting the date value using jquery date control. any guidance is appreciate.

Comment: how did you solve it finally?! I have the same problem .the mystery is ,it works on VS , or even stranger onClick button (date picker value will be passed) but not on datepicker change event !

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to capture the http request via your navigator's developer tool ? do you see the request and what is the response from the server ?

Answer (score 1):

Set customErrors mode to "off" (in your web.config) and then investigate response in firebug, you should see nice stack trace returned from the server. Just make sure that your catch block (which you didn't post) looks like:

```
try
{
// your code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 throw;
}
```

(Make sure that you are not doing throw ex; because that way you will lose stack trace).

You can continue from there.

As a blind guess it might happen that: 
1. Service.Create(model); fails (perhaps you don't have perimissions from that machine to access "Service", or 
2. It might happen that you are posting too much data, so try increasing maxRequest length in

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="1200" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It would be useful to know your stack trace, though.

Comment: great answer. custom error off showed the following error message: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM but the issue is that it works in VS and not in IIS. i am setting a value = 1/2/2011 using jquery calendar control

Comment: Locally, check your datetime value in debug, it might happen that it is not passing well, in your local copy, too, but is set to some default value in that Service.Create(model) call (which is still a great mistery for me since I have no idea what it does but most likely your problem is inside it).

Comment: Also, you should make sure that you javascript is not cached from some of your previous deployments on that server (clear browser cache to make sure that it has everything from the latest deployment).

Comment: is it because the IIS server has US datetime that has SQL DB installed and VS is in UK timezone?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, I think. Have you tried things I suggested in the two previous comments?

Comment: yes no luck but finally i found the answer. and that was changing dateformat in jquery calendar to US format. everything started to work. i have to now think of a way to display people in UK date in UK format and US in US format and db to take dates in US format

Comment: Good catch, I didn't know that you had different default date/time format setup on the server. Put a hidden field for your date value where you will have date in some standard format, and on calendar close, update that field. Then, on the server side, take value of that field instead of value you are taking now (which is probably textbox to which your calendar is attached to).

Answer (score 1):

Without changing anything in your current setup, it may just be an error in the date format. Instead of setting the date as `1/2/2011` through the calendar control, try setting it as `1/2/2011 12:00:00 PM`

Or reset `datepicker` dateFormat (other formats [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)):

```
.datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
});
```

Comment: also the mystery is why it works in VS and not in IIS server.  im really confused and cant understand it. may be its a MSSQL setting that requires it? may be jquery works differently in IIS? may be something else that makes time important

Comment: Have you FireBug'd it to see what's actually being posted?

Comment: Ok so it's sending day/month/year. Have you tried setting the dateFormat parameter to send as month/day/year? (will update answer)

Answer (score 0):

Without more info I am just taking a shot in the dark here, but it may be that you're using a relative URL, for example `/bob/fred`, and the server has a different file structure to your local application.

Lets suppose that your app is in the following structure:

```
/bob/fred <- the directory you're accessing in the $.post call
/jim/index.aspx <- the page you're calling $.post in
```

And when you put it on the server the file structure, from the application root, is like this:

```
/site/bob/fred
/site/jim/index.aspx
```

When running the app through VS 2010 this would be correct. However on the server it would require a different URL.

The next step should be checking the $.post call using Firebug - see if you're getting a 404. If so, the above info should help. If not, please post some more code.

Comment: Before you say, I appreciate that you say you've checked the URL - but by checked do you mean that you've made sure you aren't getting a 404 response?

Comment: i am using relative path but that should be fine i am guessing because dialog box shows url that is also relative. its only the save that causes an issue? but you do have a good point. what do you think i can do to test

Comment: Download Firebug (for Firefox, or Dragonfly for Opera or use the built-in dev tools for Chrome) and see what response you're getting when you click the save button. In Chrome / Opera, right click the page and click 'Inspect Element'. Now go to the Network tab at the bottom of the screen. In Firefox, right click the page and go to 'Inspect Element', now click the Net tab and refresh the page.

Comment: Ok so the file is there, just the code is not working. Can you post some more code?

Comment: added code up. its strange because it works in VS and i know that service object in the code isn't null because the dialog box shows url that shows data which is retrieved from the service object

Comment: Can you post *all* relevant code please? I believe http://pastebin.com/ is a good tool when it comes to sharing code; you just paste the code and select the language to highlight it in.

Comment: which code should i paste? please note that if i send service.create() method, it uses many other files too

Comment: i noticed it happens in ALL $.ajax post methods. do you think i need HttpGet instead as attribute of methods? or do i need something else i.e. enable some setting in IIS

Comment: I really have no clue where to start I'm afraid, not without looking at the code and ideally seeing it in action (although that would mean compiling the code locally myself so would likely take ages, and right now I'm thinking of getting some sleep).

Comment: If you have logging of 500 errors, that may be a way forward - take a look at the recent logs and see what the errors were. Or get the URL that it's trying to access (in the `.post` call) and navigate directly to it in the browser; see if you can see a 500 error. This assumes you have debugging switched on though, so that you get the nice yellow and red error page

Comment: the site isn't in IIS' virtual directory. its in root level website. does that matter?

Comment: ok how do I pass the serialised form in the url because the method takes the serialised form?

Comment: i think the answer is something else. all i want to know is why ajax post works in VS and not in IIS. it can find the page. no property is null. all configuration is correct.

Comment: ok i think i got the reason why it fails but i dont know why that is happening. i am going to update the question so you can check